# How do i build an IPA file (unsigned or signed) for an ios device on windows without a developer account using React-Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

Im making an application for ios, and I want to build the ipa file to install on my phone, but I cant since I dont have a developer certificate. can somebody please provide an answer on how to do it?

I tried to build the app with eas-cli, not knowing I had to have a dev certificate, but then I got an error so I couldnt build.

Comment: You need macOS. You need a developer account (free account is ok)

Comment: But i cant build from eas-cli when i sign in to my free account?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to show more details. What error message are you seeing?  What command are your executing.